# A colorful SVG in plain HTML is all black in React. Why?

Tags: html, svg, reactjs

I'm using React in Meteor.

When I add an SVG to the React component, style is not applied. But the very same code is working as expected in a plain HTML.

Here is my SVG code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1031 475" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="25%" id="front-rainbow-gradient">
      <stop stop-color="#00D7B9" offset="0%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#B95DD7" offset="50%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#FFB367" offset="100%"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 475h1031V0C630.46 33.34 270 208.52 0 475z"
    fill="url(#front-rainbow-gradient)" fill-opacity="0.65" />
</svg>
```

The React component:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main-header">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1031 475" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="25%" id="front-rainbow-gradient">
              <stop stop-color="#00D7B9" offset="0%"/>
              <stop stop-color="#B95DD7" offset="50%"/>
              <stop stop-color="#FFB367" offset="100%"/>
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <path d="M0 475h1031V0C630.46 33.34 270 208.52 0 475z"
            fill="url(#front-rainbow-gradient)" fill-opacity="0.65" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className="latest">
      <Container />
      </div>
      </div>
  )
  }
```

Comment: This SVG works fine, where's the code that *does not* work for you? Because that's what you're asking a question about, so we kind of need to see what you're doing (in reduced form, of course. Not a hundreds of lines long file)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added the simplified version of the React component.

Comment: That's just your render function, not a component. Create a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) by removing that JSX that does not concern placing the SVG, and adding the React code around it so it's a real component, that people can copy past into a [jsbin.com](http://jsbin/com) example or the like (or better yet, that you supply a link to) so that people can both see that you took the time to debug this problem (reducing often makes you find the problem yourself), and took the time to make sure they don't spent lots of it just to reproduce.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

classic camelCase.

```
   <stop stopColor="#00D7B9" offset="0%"/>
   <stop stopColor="#B95DD7" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stopColor="#FFB367" offset="100%"/>
```

(mind that react expects camel case properties)

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe that was the reason. First "class" vs "className", now this. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha, yeah I was looking for others. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I can only advice to use tools like https://svg2jsx.herokuapp.com/ that will cleanup the file for you, rather than doing it by hand. Cheers!