# SVG Linear Gradient is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, svg, safari

I'm doing cross browser testing on my web app that I have a gradient color element to render. This feature works well in Chrome and FireFox so far. However, It doesn't work in Safari for some reason, I hope you guys can help.

[chrome circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBFZs.png)
[safari circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4On8.png)

```
export function renderCircle(size, number, data) {
    if (number == 1) {
        return (
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={size} height={size}
                 viewBox="0 0 400 400">
                <g id="Dark_Blue">
                    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="#1DA1F2"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Logo__x2014__FIXED">
                    <path d="M163.4,305.5c88.7,0,137.2-73.5,137.2-137.2c0-2.1,0-4.2-0.1-6.2c9.4-6.8,17.6-15.3,24.1-25
                        c-8.6,3.8-17.9,6.4-27.7,7.6c10-6,17.6-15.4,21.2-26.7c-9.3,5.5-19.6,9.5-30.6,11.7c-8.8-9.4-21.3-15.2-35.2-15.2
                        c-26.6,0-48.2,21.6-48.2,48.2c0,3.8,0.4,7.5,1.3,11c-40.1-2-75.6-21.2-99.4-50.4c-4.1,7.1-6.5,15.4-6.5,24.2
                        c0,16.7,8.5,31.5,21.5,40.1c-7.9-0.2-15.3-2.4-21.8-6c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0,23.4,16.6,42.8,38.7,47.3c-4,1.1-8.3,1.7-12.7,1.7
                        c-3.1,0-6.1-0.3-9.1-0.9c6.1,19.2,23.9,33.1,45,33.5c-16.5,12.9-37.3,20.6-59.9,20.6c-3.9,0-7.7-0.2-11.5-0.7
                        C110.8,297.5,136.2,305.5,163.4,305.5" fill="#fff"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <svg width={size} height={size} viewBox='0 0 128 128'
                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' class="cluster-circle">
                <defs>
                   <linearGradient id="_MyGradient_" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
                       <stop offset="0" stopColor="#1DC4E9"/>
                       <stop offset="1"  stopColor="#0077FF"/>
                   </linearGradient>
               </defs>
                <circle cx="64" cy="64" r="58" fill="url(#_MyGradient_)" stroke="#808080" strokeOpacity="0.5" strokeWidth="8" />
                <text textAnchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".35em" fontFamily="Helvetica" fontSize="40px" fill="white">{number}</text>
            </svg>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to apply the linearGradient to and how? Is it a HTML element or a CSS element? Safari doesn't support applying SVG effects to HTML elements and its treatment of URLs within CSS files is also buggy.

Comment: it's an SVG component in JSX, which means its to HTML.

Comment: Also encountering this issue, it's relatively recent (last month) for me.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, my DOM is definitely correct after rendering by React. I'm only able to trigger this in the latest Safari (Version 11.1 (13605.1.25.1)) on High Sierra. The only strange thing I'm seeing is that `linearGradient` seems to be all lowercase in Safari DevTools, but not in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `stopColor` to dash-case:

```
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#1DC4E9"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#0077FF"/>
```

I was able to test this in Safari using your code and the circle rendered with the blue gradient from your screenshot.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stop-color

Comment: It's camel case in react which is what the OP seems to be writing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682545/a-colorful-svg-in-plain-html-is-all-black-in-react-why